# iOS Bluetooth Low Energy reconnect issue

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing an iOS application that connects to a peripheral device. The peripheral device is bonded with the phone.

Even if my application is killed by user, the phone reconnects automatically when the peripheral is in range. But this does not happens always. Does the operating system tries to reconnect automatically to bonded slave devices? I didn't find anything in the iOS Bluetooth documentation about such an automatically reconnect.

So why does this happen? I'm confused: who should deal with the reconnect: the app or the iOS operating system?

Comment: Are you using [Core Bluetooth Background Execution Modes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html)?

Comment: Yes. 'bluetooth-central' background execution mode.

Comment: Your app needs to deal with it. If you get a call to `didDisconnectPeripheral` you need to call `connect` again

Comment: iOS views BLE peripheral connections as shared resources throughout the OS and not per app. Even if one app initiates the connection, the connection is not really owned by the app. If you call `cancelPeripheralConnection` on `CBPeripheralManager`, it is not guaranteed that the connection will be dropped instantly, the OS will wait until it's sure the device is not being used anymore.  Then it will notify with `didDisconnectPeripheral` if the connection is closed.

Comment: I'm facing same issue. Do you find any solution ?  @VladBogdan